# Ошибка в PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

Вот код:

```
from os import getcwd
import pygame
import random
link_to_files = getcwd() + "\\files\\"

#Цвета

color= {        
        "white":(255,255,255),"black":(0,0,0),"red":(255,0,0),
        "green":(0,255,0),"blue":(0,0,255)
}

#Параметры окна:
#Размер = ширина, высота = (400, 300)
size = width, height = (500,500)


#Создаём экран (холст)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.init()

def draw_widgets():
    screen.fill(color['white'])
    
    #screen.fill(pygame.Color('red'), pygame.Rect(230,230,40,40)) Rect(x,y, width, height )
    for i in range(10000):
        screen.fill(pygame.color['blue'],(random.random() * width,random.random() * height))

draw_widgets()

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

---

Вот текст ошибки:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Tests>python main.py
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.6)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    draw_widgets()
  File "main.py", line 27, in draw_widgets
    screen.fill(pygame.color['blue'],(random.random() * width,random.random() * height))
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `fill(color, rect=None, special_flags=0) -> Rect`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо `pygame.color['blue']` использовать `pygame.Color('blue')`

В `pygame` `color` действительно является модулем (т.е. файлом `color.py`), и у него есть класс `Color`, который и нужно использовать

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна идея кода так как про нее ничего не написано. Предпологаю что нужно вывести 10000 синих прямоугольников чтобы они залили весь экран.

C учетом что массив цветов уже задан нужно его и использовать, иначе pygame.Color(`цвет`),

Заливка fill вторым параметром требует прямоугольник т.е. 4 значения: `[x, y, w, h]`

Если нужно сделать эффект заливки пикселями можно попробовать такие прямоугольники:

`[align(random.random() * (width + 1)), align(random.random() * (height +1)), 5, 5]`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

функция выравнивания будет такой:

```
def align(value):
  return value - value % 5
```

чтобы видеть динамические изменения нужно вызывать обновление экрана вручную:

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

Далее идет исправленный исходный код (с заливкой не пикселями так как в вопросе не указано что именно должна делать программа).

```
from os import getcwd
import pygame
import random
link_to_files = getcwd() + "\\files\\"

#Цвета
color = {        
  "white":(255,255,255),"black":(0,0,0),"red":(255,0,0),
  "green":(0,255,0),"blue":(0,0,255)
}

#Параметры окна:
#Размер = ширина, высота = (400, 300)
size = width, height = (500,500)

#Создаём экран (холст)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.init()

def draw_widgets():
    screen.fill(color["white"])
    for i in range(10000):
        screen.fill(color["blue"], [0, 0, random.random() * (width + 1)  , random.random() * (height +1) ])
        pygame.display.flip() # для того чтобы видеть обновления

draw_widgets()

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

заливка будет с левого верхнего угла:

[image: скриншот]